# Python - Tkinter Event Generation

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a GUI using for my code and finding it hard to develop what i want.

First ...

on the window an image and label appear and disappear after couple of seconds. after that a frame should arrive, followed by a menu option, when the menu option is selected it should disappear from frame and another image should appear.

```
self.gui = Tk()

def configure_window(self):

    self.gui.geometry('700x500')
    self.gui.resizable(height=False, width=False)
    self.gui.update()        

    self.welcome_label()
    self.welcome_image()


def welcome__image(self):
    image = Image.open(image path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    welcome_image = Label(master=self.gui, image=photo,  justify='center',relief='raised')
    welcome_image.image = photo
    welcome_image.pack(padx=100, pady=100)
    welcome_image.place(bordermode='outside', x=200,y=100)
    welcome_image.after(ms=1000, func=welcome_image.place_forget)


def welcome_label(self):
    welcome_label = Label(master=self.gui, text=welcome_label_text,font=welcome_label_font, justify='center',
                     state='active', fg='blue', anchor='center', pady=10, relief='raised' )

    welcome_label.place(x=100, y=350)
    welcome_label.after(ms=1000, func=welcome_label.place_forget)

def first_frame(self):
    self.first_frame = LabelFrame( master = self.gui,text='Select First File',font= 'arial 10 bold underline',  bg=self.background_colour,
                       height=200,width=690, bd=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.first_frame.pack()
    self.first_frame.place(x=0, y=0)


def select_button1(self):
    self.file_open_button1 =    Button(master=self.first_frame,text='...',state='disabled',command=self.cmd_file_select_button1)
```

when i run the code, welcome_image and welcome_frame places and forgets places after 1000 ms, but, first_frame also loads with parent widget. i want frame to arrive after the welcome_label disappears.

and the same sequence continues for LabelFrame

i have widgets in LabelFrame in which i have OptionMenu and button, i want optionMenu to disappear when user selects an option and another button should appear, same sequence in the button, button returns some sting and a label should appear in the place of button etc.

how to generate the sequence e.g. if an widget has place_forget() a sequence will be generated and another widget should be bind on that sequence. please help.

apology, if i am unable to make you understand my problem.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `.pack` and `.place` layouts in the same container widget (window or frame). And you definitely shouldn't call `.pack` and `.place` on the same widget!

Comment: @PM2Ring: it's OK to use `pack` and `place` in the same container, because `place` doesn't affect the size of the container and thus, doesn't conflict with `pack` and `grid`. Plus, in this case the OP calls `place` immediately after calling `pack` which negates the effect of `pack`. It's sloppy, but it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: @BryanOakley Interesting! Thanks for that info. I always thought that combining different layout methods was a no-no because they somehow conflicted. OTOH, I never use `.place`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: the "somehow conflicted" is because both `grid` and `pack` may resize the container, which triggers the other one to adjust the widgets, causing the container to resize and thus triggering the _other_, etc. `place` does not try to resize the container, so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: are you guys saying to move '.place' to solve my problem?